# Determine current Mac Chrome web page using Python (py-appscript)

Tags: python, google-chrome, chromium, sourceforge-appscript

So Chromium has officially added support for Applescript:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27468

I assume that this also means Chromium can be accessed by py-appscript. The question is: how? What syntax in py-appscript can I use to get the URL of the front-most tab in Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It is:

```
appscript.app("Google Chrome").windows.active_tab.URL()
```

The way I found it was by calling `.help()` successively.

So, first, I called the `appscript.app("Google Chrome").help()`, which listed out all of the app's accessible properties and alerted me that I needed to access it's `windows` property.

Then I called `appscript.app("Google Chrome").windows.help()`, which listed out the properties of `windows`, etc.

I feel like a bit of a n00b for not remembering this about Python but hopefully this information helps someone else if they are stuck on appscript.